# Length of powers of ideals generated by regular sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose R is noetherian local ring of dimension d and I is generated by a regular sequence of length d. Then why is the length of the module $\ell(R/I^n)={n+d-1\choose d}$

Answer (score 1):

This happnes as the associated graded ring is a polynomial ring.